# Why "LOAD XML FILE " in my server mysql does not work?

Tags: mysql

I want to load a xml file in a table with this command line but does not work !!

```
LOAD XML  LOCAL INFILE 'person1.xml' 
INTO TABLE person1 
ROWS  IDENTIFIED BY '<person>';
```

I tried also LOAD DATA FILE !!

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'XML  LOCAL INFILE 'person1.xml' INTO TABLE person1
>   ROWS  IDENTIFIED BY '' at line 1

this is the result !!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure that's the only thing in the query? I suspect there's something else before it, and that's causing the problem.

Comment: Syntax looks correct so I agree with Barmar, it might be caused by a second query or a part which you don't show. Maybe there is a statement before which is not closed by a `;` ? Just to make sure.. what's the output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` ?

Comment: Please indicate which version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: I use 5.1.73 version @MarcAlff .

Comment: the output is      variable_name value  local_infile ON

Comment: I'm connected to a  remote centos server with a putty from my pc and the file person1.xml is in the mysql directory so i need to load this file in mysql table .@DanFromGermany

Comment: Your MySQL version is really old, it's from 2013. That's right next to the digital stone age.

Answer (score 1):

LOAD XML DATA was added in MySQL 5.5.

See the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions

which lists as new in 5.5:

XML.  Enhancements to XML functionality, including a new LOAD XML statement. See Section 13.2.7, “LOAD XML Syntax”.

Your server version is 5.1, it does not know what LOAD XML is.